# angular material 2 md-list odd-even style

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Am trying to have a different background for odd/even rows in the md-list. 
Not sure if this is supported using Angular Material 2 - Md-list component as I don't see any documentation on this.

I believe angular 2 supports this using the ng-class-odd/ng-class-even

Answer (score 6):

You should be using below styles in your component

```
.mat-list >  .mat-list-item:nth-child(2n+1){
  background-color:red;
}
.mat-list >  .mat-list-item:nth-child(2n){
  background-color:blue;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/5cnXYNGO3o68kJvWU6MC?p=preview)**