# Angular 4 Material tabs - css not applied to header template

Tags: css, angular, angular-material2

I'd like to hide the header (Buttons) of the Angular Material Tabs, because I'm using custom navigation buttons to switch between the tabs.
https://material.angular.io/components/tabs/overview

However, it is not possible to hide the header using css. I don't know why. `md-tab-group`is an angular directive, which is replaced with the tabs template. Despite it usually shout work this way...

**HTML:**

```
     <div class="tabs">
        <md-tab-group>
           <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
           <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
        </md-tab-group>
     </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
     .tabs md-tab-header, .tabs .mat-tab-header {
        display: none;
     }
```

Comment: why there is a `,` comma in place ?

Comment: This way you can declare a style for different css classes. But this is not causing the problem, i've also tried it separately.

Comment: In the `LESS file` you can use them. can you create a plunker to reproduce. Refer this [**answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351202/angular-material-2-md-list-odd-even-style/42597460#42597460) if it helps you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try the following css:

```
::ng-deep .tabs .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels {
        display: none;
}
```

html:

```
<md-tab-group class="tabs">
  <md-tab label="Tab 1">Content 1</md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Tab 2">Content 2</md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NvbKdIPzTWA4Q7JMx5O2?p=info)

Comment: `::ng-deep` is the shadow-piercing combinator provided by angular that can be used to override prebuilt stylesheet's css classes. You can read about it [here](https://hackernoon.com/the-new-angular-ng-deep-and-the-shadow-piercing-combinators-deep-and-drop-4b088dbe459). And for rest of the css, from Developer Tools I found that  `mat-tab-labels` class needs to be overriden to hide the header buttons instead of `mat-tab-header`. The extra `.tabs` class is in there so that this style applies to only the `md-tab-group` where you use the `tabs` class, instead of all overriding all `md-tab-group`.

Comment: this worked for me without ::ng-deep for angular 5. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me replacing:

```
.mat-tab-header{
  background: red !important;
}
```

to:

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-header{
  background: red !important;
}
```

worked !

Comment: you can override anything with ::ng-deep. The problem with these all answers is that there are cases when you are not allowed to use ::ng-deep or when you have a bunch of the tabs and that same style gets applied to all of them (when using ::ng-deep).

Answer (score 0):

```
Angular4:

template:  
<mat-tab-group class="tabs">
    <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>Tasks<ng-template>
        <app-ongoingtasks></app-ongoingtasks>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

css:
::ng-deep .tabs .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels {
    margin: auto;
    width: 60%;
}

Perfect!
```